# DBeaver - start running code after declaring and setting a variable

Tags: sql, variables, dbeaver, declare

I have a simple *select* statement in DBeaver which uses the same table name twice.
To avoid typing it in twice, I have a *@set* statement to store the table name.
However, if I select everything and try to run it, it stalls at the *@set* statement and doesn't move on to the *select* statement.
What keyword or command am I missing to enable me to run this code in one go?

If this were "normal" SQL, I would probably use a *return* or *go* command, but DBeaver doesn't seem to like either of these.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> What keyword or command am I missing to enable me to run this code in one go?

To run a `@set` statement and a `select` statement in one go in DBeaver, you can use the semicolon `;` character as a separator like that:

```
@set table_name = 'my_table';
select * from ${table_name};
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi Zufar, 
thanks for replying but I still can't get it to work.
It keeps getting stuck on the table statistics screen.

Comment: Further research would indicate that my code was correct, I was just using the wrong command.  I was executing the "query" instead of the "script"!